# When using asterisk ari, am i meant to develop my own softphone ?

Tags: asterisk, sip, pjsip, pbx, freepbx

i'm a quite a rookie at asterisk development, i understand some basic fundamental concepts of channels and bridges . i understand that channels are created by the channel driver written in c when using a dialplan configuration.i have been able to configure sip phones to make inbound calls and outbound and also been able to configure a local sip provider to make trunk calls. The issue i have is with ari, what i dont understand is if i am meant to develop a soft sip phone (on a browser) from where a channels rest call is initiated. and if i'm mean to do that , how will the audio be communicated via the browser.

Answer (score -1):

ARI designed to control asterisk via rest-like interface

It have no any relation to softphone. You can use hardphone and ARI, no problem in that.

"audio be comunicated via the browser" = WebRTC

Comment: My question further is how can ARI be used with a sip phone or a hardphone ?

Comment: Softphone should connect to ur service(cisco hardphone via xml services for example) after that ur service authorize to ARI and proxy actions.

Answer (score -1):

I use docker composition and developing with ari4java library, so via the composition I define asterisk service, within it I add all needed configuration files (sip.conf, ari.conf etc.) and then use the command 'docker-compose up' to run the composition. Before/after that I created a SIP account using linphone or zoiper (both are soft phones), that was defined at sip.conf file. When the composition is up, it will register your SIP account and then you can dial to another SIP.

asterisk service example in composition (docker-compose.yaml file):

```
version: '2'
services:
  asterisk: 
    image: registry.gitlab.com/cloudonix/docker/asterisk-docker:14
    volumes: 
      - ./configuration/extensions.conf:/etc/asterisk/extensions.conf:ro
      - ./configuration/http.conf:/etc/asterisk/http.conf:ro
      - ./configuration/ari.conf:/etc/asterisk/ari.conf:ro
      - ./configuration/sip.conf:/etc/asterisk/sip.conf:ro

   ports:
      - 8088:8088
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_address: //add ip address
```

Docker documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/

Download zoiper: https://www.zoiper.com/en/voip-softphone/download/current